# Hide all text behind a header transparent but not images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Hi !

I need your help to **hide** **all** **text** **behind** a **transparent** **header** ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6ctk.jpg)) cause isn't readable.. the image isn't problem but only text..
I want to keep the header transparent..  .float-menu.container{background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);

I can't find a solution..

thank you..!

```css
#myHeader {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  top: 150px;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
  background: red;
}

#paragraf {
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="myHeader">
    This is my header element.
  </div>

  <p id="paragraf"><b>Note:</b> I want to hide all text</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Please add code here so that we can see what's the issue

Comment: like this for example
https://jsfiddle.net/vkusq9zo/

Answer (score 0):

Made few changes in your CSS and HTML:

- Added a div with `.wrapper` class and all the p tags moved into it.
- Then added this CSS style to the wrapper:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px; 
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Explanation:

- Added absolute position to the wrapper and set the `top: 50px` (height of the header so that they won't overlap with each other.
- Overflow set to scroll, so that p tag content won't be visible behind the header.
- and max-height set to `calc(100vh - 50px)`, subtracted 50px (header height) from whole viewport height (100vh)

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```css
#myHeader {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
}

body {
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px; 
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="myHeader">
  This is my header element.
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p id="paragraf"><b>Note:</b> I want to hide all text</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposition but I think it's the same like a header no transparent..

I want to hide only text and not the images.. ? we can see the images under the header but not the text of body..

I hope someone can help me.. Thanks

Comment: Did you even check the code? The headers background is white in color with opacity 0.4 because of which the pinkish color is visible on header, try to change the body background you'll see the transparency of header and the text will not be visible and image will be visible

Comment: Yes i check your code but if i have one image in the content, the header hide the image also.. https://jsfiddle.net/8gmqhkjo/1/

Comment: To achieve this you also need javascript and its quite difficult to achieve this

Comment: i don't know very well javascript.. but i heart that it's possible with DOM of navigateur..

Comment: anyone can help me please ?